# Joomla Database import does not work

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, mariadb

i made a backup of my joomla MySQL database using the export function of phpMyAdmin.
When i try to import this backup file, it gives me a lot of errors like "You have an error in your SQL syntax..." even if the SQL looks quite correct.

Here is a small part of the backup, which doesnt even work:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set parent.`,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set lft.`,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set rgt.`,
  `level` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
  `rules` varchar(5120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When i run this command, i get the following error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Nested set parent.`,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested ' at line 3
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong here? This code was automatically generated by phpMyAdmin and it looks like valid SQL to me!

Im using:
phpMyAdmin version 4.5.5
PHP version 5.6.14
Server version 10.0.23-MariaDB-0+deb8u1
Joomla version 3.5.0

Comment: I seem to remember there were some odd issues like this with phpMyAdmin 4.5.? which were fixed in phpMyAdmin 4.6

Comment: Any idea how i can fix them manually? Import of the .sql file using phpMyAdmin version 4.0.10 doesnt work either

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys i found out the problem myself:

It seems the line

```
COMMENT AS `Nested set parent.`,
```

is no valid SQL. Correct would be

```
COMMENT 'Nested set parent.',
```

like you can see in the other lines.
I dont know why phpMyAdmin creates a MySQL Dump with invalid SQL, but this caused the problem.

Comment: As you've discovered, there was a problem with some of the phpMyAdmin 4.5 releases; this was fixed by 4.6.0. You can, of course, edit the file manually (or with your favorite text/string/stream editor) to change the backticks ` to single quotes '  (being careful not to change lines that are supposed to be backticks).